# Confusion in subquery in select statement

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

This is my syntax:

```
select firstname from (select * from inquiry where id = 2 ) as inner   ;
```

I am having confusion as where to put the alias name for table. I used the above syntax, but it results in an error:

> You have error in your sta........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER` is a MySQL reserved keyword and will throw an error if you try to use it as an alias.

Either place backticks (`) around the word "inner" or just use a different alias:

```
SELECT a.firstname 
FROM   (SELECT * FROM inquiry WHERE id = 2) a
```